# Entity Framework Core 2.1 Add Migration System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We use to get the following error when we try to run add-migration.
We use Entity Framework Core 2.1.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.TableMapping.<>c.b__10_0(IEntityType t)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetSortedProperties(TableMapping target)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue for this is a mismatch between DataContextModelSnapshot file and your entity classes. Usually this happen due to merge conflicts in the DataContextModelSnapshot  file.

It's very hard to find the mismatch just by going through the history of the DataContextModelSnapshot file.
Therefore the easiest solution for this is to;

- Delete the Snapshot file.
- Run Add-Migration 'Migration_Name' (This is
  going to create the snapshot file from the scratch and also create a
  new Migration file).
- Delete the Newly Created Migration file
  manually.
- Now you can start adding Add-Migration for the new changes.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but found it was because I named a previous migration `DateOnly`

see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26954

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem with `DateTimeOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the solution proposed by Tharindu Jayasinghe!Before you delete anything, ensure the state of your development environment.

In my case I deleted two attributes and added three new ones.

```
col1 // was deleted in class
col2 // was deleted in class

col3 // was added in class
col4 // was added in class
col5 // was added in class
```

In my migration class I then received the following result:

```
rename col1, col3
rename col2, col4
add col5
```

When I then called "dotnet ef database update" I got the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

So I went and adjusted the migration class by hand:

**Up:**

```
drop col1
drop col2

add col3
add col4
add col5
```

**Down:**

```
add col1
add col2

drop col3
drop col4
drop col5
```

Then I called "dotnet ef database update" again, which ran without any problems!
The database was then adjusted as I expected :-)